# Android WebViewClient before and after load resources

Tags: java, android, webkit

I would like to be notify each time before and after the WebViewClient loads a resource.

I found [onLoadResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onLoadResource%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) and it seams to be before load.

Is there any possibility to be notified after the resource is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code-

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
     @Override
     public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) 
     {
         //Do something
         super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
         //Do something
         return true;

     }

     @Override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
    {
      //Do something
      super.onPageFinished(view, url);

     }
    }
```

It may help you.

Comment: Thanks I think this only supports initial page loading. I want to know about ajax too.